# TimeTrigger/Scheduler in Windows 10 (UWP) for less than 15 minutes

Tags: scheduler, uwp

I figured out using TimeTrigger is the way for the scheduled background task on Windows 10 (UWP). However it looks like minimum number we need to give is 15 minutes. Just wondering, how the Alarm and reminders work for Windows 10 even we schedule it to run for next 1 minute.

I am looking for a solution that should trigger a task in a specific time which include less than 15 minutes.

Can any one shed some light on this?

Comment: Alarm and reminders are different. You don't need `TimeTrigger` for them. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31740884/can-i-create-an-alarm-app-for-window-universal-app

Comment: I went through the Sample code on Github and found that the Alarm and other toasts are shown based on the button click. Do you know how this can be attached to a timer that works even the Foreground app is not running? I am not sure, how it runs on scheduled time. Is that done by "ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().AddToSchedule" as Jeffrey pointed out? Any code for that on Github Windows 10 samples?

Comment: Any idea as to how to schedule-run a block of code in this similar way (may be less than 15 minutes, based on the time user selects)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Alarm & Clock application was using Scheduled Toast Notification rather than background task.

[image]

Here is the sample code to schedule a toast in 10 seconds.

```
namespace UWPApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        private Random random = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);

        const string TOAST = @"
<toast>
  <visual>
    <binding template=""ToastGeneric"">
      <text>Sample</text>
      <text>This is a simple toast notification example</text>
      <image placement = ""AppLogoOverride"" src=""oneAlarm.png"" />
    </binding>
  </visual>
  <actions>
    <action content = ""check"" arguments=""check"" imageUri=""check.png"" />
    <action content = ""cancel"" arguments=""cancel""/>
  </actions>
  <audio src =""ms-winsoundevent:Notification.Reminder""/>
</toast>";


        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var when = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(10);

            var offset = new DateTimeOffset(when);

            Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument xml = new Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument();

            xml.LoadXml(TOAST);

            ScheduledToastNotification toast = new ScheduledToastNotification(xml, offset);

            toast.Id = random.Next(1, 100000000).ToString();

            ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().AddToSchedule(toast);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see. So, will this run on the background? Would AddToSchedule run even the foreground app is not running? Is there any way I can execute a block of code in less than 10 minutes?

Comment: Any idea as to how to schedule-run a block of code in this similar way (may be less than 15 minutes, based on the time user selects)?

Comment: This actually answers my question on Alarm and its timing. Marking as answer.